# How to dynamically build a resources (V1ResourceRequirements) object for a kubernetes pod in airflow

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow

I'm currently migrating a DAG from airflow version 1.10.10 to 2.0.0.

This DAG uses a custom python operator where, depending on the complexity of the task, it assigns resources dynamically.
The problem is that the import used in v1.10.10 (**airflow.contrib.kubernetes.pod import Resources**) no longer works. I read that for v2.0.0 I should use **kubernetes.client.models.V1ResourceRequirements**, but I need to build this resource object dynamically.
This might sound dumb, but I haven't been able to find the correct way to build this object.

For example, I've tried with

```
            self.resources = k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
                request_memory=get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['memory'],
                limit_memory=get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['memory_l'],
                request_cpu=get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['cpu'],
                limit_cpu=get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['cpu_l']
            )
```

or

```
            self.resources = k8s.V1ResourceRequirements(
                requests={'cpu': get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['cpu'],
                          'memory': get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['memory']},
                limits={'cpu': get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['cpu_l'],
                        'memory': get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['memory_l']}
            )
```

(get_k8s_resources_mapping(resource_request)['xxxx'] just returns a value depending on the resource_request, like '2Gi' for memory or '2' for cpu)

But they don't seem to work. The task fails.

So, my question is, how would you go about correctly building a V1ResourceRequirements in Python?
And, how should it look in the executor_config attribute of the task instance? Something like this, maybe?

```
'resources': {'limits': {'cpu': '1', 'memory': '512Mi'}, 'requests': {'cpu': '1', 'memory': '512Mi'}}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The The proper syntax is:

For **apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes>=5.3.0**:

```
from kubernetes import client
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.pod import KubernetesPodOperator

KubernetesPodOperator(
    ...,
    container_resources = client.V1ResourceRequirements(
        requests={"cpu": "1000m", "memory": "8G"},
        limits={"cpu": "16000m", "memory": "128G"}
    )
)
```

If you would like to generate it dynamically simply replace the values in requests/limits with function that returns the [expected string](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/V1ResourceRequirements.md).

---

Below are changes needed for the code to work on earlier versions.

For **apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes<5.3.0 and >=4.2.0**:

change import path to:

```
from airflow.providers.cncf.kubernetes.operators.kubernetes_pod import KubernetesPodOperator
```

For **apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes<4.2.0**:

Change `container_resources` to `resources`